# Laplace operator on $H^{-1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb R^n$ (say,  with smooth boundary for simplicity). I am looking for a reference for the fact that if $f \in H^{-1}$ (that is, the dual of $H^1 = W^{1,2}$)  then, there is a weak solution $u \in H^1$ of $\Delta u = f$ in $\Omega$, $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. In order words, the operator $\Delta:H^1_0 \to H^{-1}$ is an isomorphism.

I have found in many books the equivalent statement for $\Delta:H^1_0 \cap H^{k}\to H^{k-2}$ for $k \geq 2$, but not for $k=1$. Theorem 2.44 in [these lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf) gives what I want, but I would like to have a proper reference from a book/paper that I could cite. If you know of a reference dealing with the analogous question on compact manifolds, it would be even better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the Lax-Milgram lemma. It should be covered in any book on, e.g., finite elements.

Comment: P. Grisvard's book, Girault-Raviart, Necas, or Lions-Maganes book. Once you show the well-posedness of the BVP together with an a priori estimate ($\|\cdot\|_{1}$ norm continuously depends on the data's $\|\cdot\|_{-1}$ norm), you have established the result you want (isomorphism).